# JavaScript: Split string with text on each side of equal sign (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following example string:

```
"msg=Hello World! param1=42 param2=abcd efgh"
```

and I want to split this into an array as such:

```
['msg', 'Hello World!', 'param1', '42', 'param2', 'abcd efgh']`
```

I have attempted it with the following `.split(/=/);`, however this doesn't account for whitespace. How could I split the string to yield that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex and grab capture group #1 and group #2:

```
/(\w+)=(.+?)(?= \w+=|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX2lE6/1)

**Code:**

```js
var re = /(\w+)=(.+?)(?= \w+=|$)/gm; 
var str = 'msg=Hello World! param1=42 param2=abcd efgh';
var m;
var result=[];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    result.push(m[1]);
    result.push(m[2]);
}

document.write("<pre>" + result + "</pre>");
```

**Output:**

```
["msg", "Hello World!", "param1", "42", "param2", "abcd efgh"]
```

Comment: You forgot the `g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern with the [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method:

```
/([^=\s]+)=([^=\s]*(?:\s+[^=\s]+)*)(?!\S)/g
# ^         ^      ^               ^---- ensures that a whitespace or the end of 
# |         |      |                     the string follows
# |         |      '-------------------- eventual parts of the value after 
# |         |                            whitespaces
# +---------+--------------------------- all characters that aren't whitespaces
# |         '- optional to allow         or equal signs
# |            empty values
# '- at least one for the key
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO8fB1/1)

This pattern avoids eventual trailing spaces and succeeds even if the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The short alternative solution using `String.match` and `Array.concat` functions:

```
var str = "msg=Hello World! param1=42 param2=abcd efgh", splitted = [];
str.match(/\w+?=[^=]+(?!\w+=)(\s|$)/gi).forEach(function(v){
    splitted = splitted.concat(v.trim().split("="));
});

console.log(splitted);   // ["msg", "Hello World!", "param1", "42", "param2", "abcd efgh"]
```